# signal only works in main thread of the main interpreter in fast api background task

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, uvicorn

I wanted to use background tasks feature of fastapi to do time consuming task.Once the tasks get completed, i need to notify to the service present in a remote server about the `task status`. Currently, the python application is running in a docker. The below function throws the error `signal only works in main thread of the main interpreter`. I have gone through many threads in stack overflow, but nothing helped me.

```
def send_data_source_ack(community_id, dataSourceId,status='LOADED'):
    config = get_env_config()
    uri = '/api/rpc/chat-bot/data-source/ack'
    request = f"?status={status}&communityId="+str(community_id)+"&dataSourceId="+str(dataSourceId)
    url = config.APIBaselURL.url + uri + request
    response = requests.post(url, data={},verify=False)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        api_requests.debug(f'POST request successful for {community_id} with status {response.text}')
    else:
        api_requests.debug(f'POST request unsuccessful for {community_id} with status code {response.status_code}')
```

Below is the docker file that i use to run the application

```
FROM python:3.9.17-slim-bullseye

WORKDIR /src

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install libpq-dev gcc 
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 9856

# CMD [ "python", "-m" , "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--port=5000"]

CMD ["uvicorn","chatbot.run:app","--host","0.0.0.0","--port","9856","--workers","4","--reload"]
```

Below is the fastapi routes file

```
@app.post('/data-config/trigger',status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
async def handle_data_config_trigger(
    request:Request,
    tasks:BackgroundTasks,
    community_id: int =  Query(alias='community_id'),
    data_source_type: str = Query(alias='data_source_type')
    ):
    data_config = await request.json()
    data_config_source = DataConfigSource(data_config=data_config)
   
    # Background task 
   
    tasks.add_task(run_training_in_background_task,
             community_id,data_source_type,
             data_config_source.data_config)

    return f"{data_source_type} started for community_id {community_id}"


async def run_training_in_background_task(community_id,data_source_type,data_config):
    try:
        logger.debug(f'Hit data config trigger for {community_id}')
        if data_source_type == "PDF":
            trigger_pdf_data_config(community_id, data_config)
        
        
        #  Below is the function that throws the error 
        send_data_source_ack(community_id, data_config.id,status='LOADED')


    except Exception as e:
        logger.debug(f'Exception thrown in processing the training for community id - {community_id}')
```

If you have any alternatives on how to fix it, please let me know. Thank you